# Intercepting and modyfing mouse events headed for a third-party application?

Tags: java, mouseevent

How can I intercept and modify mouse events (x/y coordinates, acceleration, etc.) via Java, before they reach a third party application?

The application is known beforehand (so something like "java myApp 3rdPartyApp" is possible, if it helps). Do note that the third-party application may be very resource-intensive.

I guess what I'm asking is how can I make a Java app that serves as a layer between the real mouse events and the third-party application so that the third-party app receives the modified events but not the original ones sent by the OS? Is this even possible with Java?

Comment: Which GUI layer are you using AWT/SWING, SWT, other ?

Comment: I haven't decided yet so any GUI specific solution is okay.

Comment: I don't have a real answer, only a guess: maybe you could intercept MouseListeners with aspects.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 pure java solutions.

First, you can connect to the AWT event queue and get all UI events: `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue()`
Unfortunately I am not sure you can modify these events but you can read them and you can simulate events.

Second you can create transparent window over your third party application where you can catch  all UI events and then simulate them using `java.awt.Robot`.
Please see [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/translucent_shaped_windows/) how to create transparent window. I tried this method and see that it works well.

Comment: Ah. So by layering a window over it, the third-party application doesn't receive mouse events (or I assume, any other events) because it's not in focus? How does Robot work in terms of this focus? And how do I get some basic info about the third-party app such as dimensions?